# Can't call instance method from index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm trying to call method (instance method) which I have defined in the controller from the `index.html.erb` view.

records_controller.rb:

```
def calc_cell_balance
   4
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<% @records.each do |r| %>
  <%= r.calc_cell_balance %><br>
<% end %>
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `calc_cell_balance' for #<Record:0x35d18d8>
```

I don't want to make it a class method because it's bad design.
If I put the method definition in `record.rb` (the model), it's working.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, since it's wrong to access the model from the view, but it's the only thing working.

How can I resolve this?
Thanks.

Comment: How can you say that it is wrong and bad design?

Comment: In fact it is the correct way and it suits the **Fat Model and Skinny Controller** of `MVC Design`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put an instance method in your controller, `RecordsController`, but you are trying to  call the method on an instance of the `Record` class. This doesn't make sense at all. Your `@records` are all `Record` instances. You would have to do something like:

```
RecordsController.new.calc_cell_balance
```

BUT DON'T DO THAT! Your controller is there to just direct what needs to be done, and shouldn't have methods that are called outside of the controller instance itself.

Your method probably belongs in the `Record` model, or maybe in a helper. It is not at all wrong to access the model from the view. That's the main thing that people do. If you really wanted to not be calling any methods from the view, you could try to gather up all the information in the controller like this:

```
@records = Record.all
@records_calc_cell_balance = @records.collect(&:calc_cell_balance)
```

And then you have parallel arrays of data, but that's just silly. Calling model methods from the view is fine. Or, if you feel the method is too view-centric (like maybe you want a method to tell you what CSS class to use), put that in a view helper, which is what it's for.